# How to implement IDocHostShowUI in SHDocVw.InternetExplorer using VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer, alert

I am trying to trap the alert messages. By implementing IDocHostShowUI ShowMessage method its working fine for AxWebBrowser control. Here is that code

```
Dim oleObject As IOleObject = AxWebBrowser1.GetOcx()
If oleObject IsNot Nothing Then oleObject.SetClientSite(Me)
```

But it is not working for SHDocVw.InternetExplorer. Here is the code I tried

```
 Dim oleObject As IOleObject = ie.Document
 If oleObject IsNot Nothing Then oleObject.SetClientSite(Me)
```

Can anybody help me to implement it for SHDocVw.InternetExplorer.

Comment: Sure looks like you are trying to do this for an *out-of-process* browser.  That cannot work.

Comment: Yes it is an out of process browser, Many people pointed me to use IDocHostShowUI ShowMessage method for trapping alerts. If this way is incorrect, Kindly help me to find the correct way.